# check for IE and display another page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a web app which is currently not rendering in IE. For the time being, I want to check for IE and display another page for IE visitors. How can I do it? Do I need javascript or PHP?

Comment: There are already a lot similar questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+detection

Comment: sorry abt that. wen i typed the TOPIC in the 'ask a question page', none came in the field below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` you could use IE's conditional comments, combined with a meta tag or javascript like below:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/IEonly.php" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Ugh, you beat me by half a minute...typing code on iPhone is *not* the wy to go... =/

Comment: I'd go with conditional comments before I went with any other method as the USER_AGENT isn't quite what it was supposed to have been... and other methods are likely to break before the conditional comments ever will.

Comment: ricebowl +1 for having the idea, and being so addicted you even SO on your iphone :P

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP function, i prefer PHP for this because ideally you shall know the browser at the server side rather than client side in your case.

```
function detect_ie()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This snippet will return true of the browser is IE, in this snippet the browser version is not being checked as it isnt required by your question

hope this helps

Comment: thanks. how can i redirect it to another page? i want to use relative URL here.

Comment: the server as well as a client side javascript can look at the useragent. neither is a 100% solution as browsers sometimes mask the useragent to look like other browsers (to actually avoid being browser detected).

in javascript i think you can get the useragent from navigator.userAgent

Answer (score 1):

PHP can do it. Check `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can do it as well. You have the **navigator** object, which has a bunch of properties identifying the browser:

- **appName**: The name of the browser.
- **appVersion**: The version of the
  browser.

Depending on what browser you have, you can do a redirect to another page then.